# Apex Class Extension: Updating related field using standard controller

Tags: class, controller, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am relatively new to Apex:

Im trying to save a related field via my visualforce page, the apex class currently in use returns this error:

Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 000000000000000; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, record id cannot be empty key: []
Error is in expression '{!save}' in component  in page masseditcontact: Class.ContactExt.save: line 28, column 1

What I have tried so far is to refer to the field on my visualforce page - Contact.Account.Organization_Size__c - however when I try and update it with the save method in my class it seems to throw the error above.

```
public class ContactExt {

public Contact record {get; set;}
public String city {
    get {
        return record.Account.Organization_Size__c;
    }
    private set;
}

public ContactExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {


    record = (Contact)controller.getRecord();


}


public PageReference save(){

    update record


//try{

//update record;
//}
//catch (QueryException e)
//{
//record = new Contact();
//}

return null;
```

}

}

Visualforce markup

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactExt" recordSetVar="unused" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' || contains($CurrentPage.URL, 'lightning.force.com')}">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS221, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.MassEditCSS}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.UtilJS}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.LightningMassEditJS}" />
<apex:includeScript value="support/api/42.0/interaction.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="support/console/42.0/integration.js"/>


<div class="mass-update-mass-edit" id="mass-update-mass-edit">
    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" id="cancel-modal">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="closeCancelModal();">
                    <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS221, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Return</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <p>Are you sure you wish to return?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="closeCancelModal();">No</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="goBack();">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open" id="cancel-modal-backdrop"></div>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlock >
                Note: All modifications made on the page will be lost if Return button is clicked without clicking the Save button first. 
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' || contains($CurrentPage.URL, 'lightning.force.com')}">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" status="lightningSavingStatus" reRender="table" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Return" onclick="openCancelModal();" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" reRender="table" />
                    <apex:actionStatus id="lightningSavingStatus" >
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                            <div id="spinning" class="slds-spinner_container">
                                <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium" role="alert">
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>               
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed != 'Theme4d' && !contains($CurrentPage.URL, 'lightning.force.com')}">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" status="savingStatus" reRender="table" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Return" action="{!cancel}" onclick="return confirmCancel()" />
                    <apex:actionStatus id="savingStatus" >
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                            <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="a" id="table">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                <support:clickToDial number="{!a.Phone}" entityId="{!a.Id}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Mobile Phone">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.MobilePhone}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Email}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Title">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Title}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Account">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Description">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Description}"/>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Organisation Size">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Organization_Size__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Organisation Size">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Account.Organization_Size__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your visualforce code look like? Do you have `StandardController="Contact"` on it?

Comment: Hi I have updated the post to show visualforce markup. Yes I have Contact as the standard controller

Comment: You are using the `StandardSetController` in your apex constructor. This is meant to be used with multiple records, but you are using it as if there is only 1 record. If you change your constructor to take instead a `ApexPages.StandardController stdController` it should work

Comment: Hi so when I do that I am getting an unknown constructor error which is why I chose to go for the StandardSetController as it is asking me to do that as a fix ---- : Error: Unknown constructor 'ContactExt.ContactExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)' 
Quick Fix Create Apex method 'ContactExt.ContactExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)'

Comment: Take out `recordSetVar` from your page definition

Comment: So I have taken that out and now I am getting this error ---- Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.selected'

Comment: I think you should step back from this and understand the fundamentals of visual force. [This is a good guide to get accustomed to it](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals)